# latex: how to "\input" a file whose filename depends on "~"?

Tags: latex, input, filenames

in a latex file called "main.tex" i can write the line

```
\input /home/user1/defs.tex
```

to input the conents of "defs.tex" at the position of that command.

now i want to generalize this, so that any user can compile the tex-document and "defs.tex" inside his home-directory is being inserted. my first guess

```
\input ~/defs.tex
```

didnt work. does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I recommend you ask over at http://tex.stackexchange.com where it's for TeX/LaTeX specific questions

Answer (score 0):

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1728/accessing-environment-variables-within-a-document

Thus, it would seem that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\immediate\write18{echo $HOME >/tmp/foo.tex}
\begin{document}
\input{var}
\end{document}
```

might do the trick. Or some such.

NOTE: I'm not a TeX expert, so be sure to read the referenced article carefully, and be prepared to experiment.